# Writing "clean" integration tests - REST using jersey 2 and Spring

Tags: spring, rest, integration-testing, jersey-2.0, spring-test

I would like the test case written below to be a "clean" test i.e automatically rollback database changes after the test.

```
@Test
public void testUpdate(){
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
    Name name = new Name(1L,"Updated","Updated");
    Response response = client
            .target("http://localhost:8080/jersey-spring/name/").request().header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(name));
    Assert.assertTrue(response.getStatus() == 200);
}
```

The rest services are deployed using `jetty-maven-plugin`during integration tests. The problem I am facing now is that I cannot use `spring test` `transactional` tests which means that any state changes to the database needs to be cleaned up manually after tests which is very cumbersome.

So my question is what is a suggested approach to run "clean" integration tests when using `jersey` as REST provider. I have tried using `JerseyTest` as well and also face the same problem.

For various reasons I cannot replace Jersey with Spring MVC.

***Update***

1. There is no mocking involved. The test is end to end.
2. I like to be close to production config for integration tests and hence no in-memory DB is used for integration tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make your REST handler method participate in a transaction that wraps your test code, it's just not possible. What you can do, however, is use DBUnit to bring the database into a clean state before and/or after the test.

I would especially recommend using [Spring Test DBUnit library](https://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/) due to its fantastic annotation-driven integration with Spring.

Also, I would recommend using Docker to provision your database since relying on a local database is just not a good practice since your build process will have external dependencies and will require having a DB on both the CI server and each dev machine. I've previously used [Overcast](https://github.com/xebialabs/overcast), here's a [fine example of how to use it with Docker](http://blog.xebia.com/fast-and-easy-integration-testing-with-docker-and-overcast/).

Comment: I have reached the same conclusion as well.Thanks for the docker tip. We tend to use a lot of procedures(legacy) in our code, so DB unit is not an option for me. I guess docker+oracle is the way to go.

Comment: Why would having procedures stop you from using DBUnit? You would initialize your DB (procedures included) before the suite by either using a script (e.g. schema.sql) or by running your migration tool. After that, you're free to populate and verify your data with DBUnit. Trust me, been there, done that :)

Answer (score 3):

I have used the following configuration for many Spring+Jersey2 projects and it works fine.

- Use `JerseyTest` and extend it in your test class
- Use [mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito) or [powermock](/questions/tagged/powermock) to mock your services in your REST controller
- This is important. Use an in-memory database (I prefer [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)) and create a test application context targeting this in memory database. So you don't have to worry about data integrity etc.
- Configure your test class by overriding `configure()` method of `JerseyTest`, inject your mocks and bind any relevant services of your REST controller to Jersey Context.

Here is an example:

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    // Bind factories of classes to be mocked.
    AbstractBinder binder = new AbstractBinder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bindFactory(MockCrawlerManagerFactory.class).to(CrawlerManager.class);
            bindFactory(MockUrlQueueServiceFactory.class).to(UrlQueueService.class);
            bindFactory(MockSitemapServiceFactory.class).to(SitemapService.class);
            bindFactory(MockCrawlerServiceFactory.class).to(CrawlerService.class);
            bindFactory(MockUrlContentServiceFactory.class).to(UrlContentService.class);
            // Other services to mock ....
        }
    };

    // This is your main Spring application
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Bootstrap.class);

    // And create your Jersey context here, register REST controller to Jersey context
    return new ResourceConfig().registerClasses(RestController.class, JacksonJsonProvider.class, JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class)
            .packages("com.company.foo.crawler.rest", "com.company.foo.crawler.exception").register(binder).property("contextConfig", context);
}
```

- And begin writing tests :)

An example test:

```
    @Test
    public void testCreateCrawlerWithNoConfiguration() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    String mockUrl = "/version/" + VERSION + "/crawlers";
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("configurationId", "null");
    data.put("startUrl", "http://blog.ahmetbutun.net");
    Future<Response> asyncRes = target(mockUrl).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).header("userId", MOCK_CRAWLER_VALID_USER_ID).header("token", AUTHENTICATION_HEADER)
            .async().post(Entity.json(data));

    RestResponse response = asyncRes.get().readEntity(RestResponse.class);

    Assert.assertNotNull(response);
    Assert.assertEquals(AppConstants.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_CONFIGURATION_ID_EXCEPTION, response.getStatusCode());
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), response.getMessage().getStatus());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My tests are end to end which means there is no mocking involved. I also like to test against real database, so I use oracle local database for integration tests as well .. The problem i face is that the client code executes in  a separate thread thus it is not aware of my "test" transactions ..

Answer (score 2):

Just giving my 2 cents. There are specific things i use on my stack  so it may be just me and may not suit your stack. It is worth mentioning none the less

I am assuming you will be using some ORM framework for performing DB operations , when i create sessions on my tests , i point my hibernate to an in memory H2 (my hbm config on test point to H2).

I use  liquibase for my database migration  and on tests i point them to these H2 database (you can do this from the set-up of the tests). My DAO's then use this DB for operations , here i can test my DB operations and write assertions as well.

Comment: Thanks. Like I said below . I used oracle. However the real problem I face is how to make sure that the client code and the actual rest call happens in the same transaction ?

Comment: Just for my understanding @ArunM , You want Test calling client ---> [ Server (REST API) --->DB - logic and DB In a transaction ] --> Response to client  ,usually  your test is your client right. It can never participate in a resource driven transaction on the server right ?

Comment: Yes, You are right. It can never be a part of resource driven  transaction. However Spring has a solution to address this using MockMvc, I am searching for a jersey equivalent or even a hack which can help do a full end to end test in a single transaction so that I dont have  to manually clean up the database after every test.